# apply a code patch to subdirectories of each project

Tags: drupal, subdirectory, patch, code-patching

I have over 10+ drupal websites and I need to apply a patch to each one. currently my patch resides in **/home/201803.patch** and my drupal websites is in the same folder. Currently I have to cd into each directory and then run the following command:

**patch -p1 < ../201803.patch**

but I want to just be able to do each one from the /home folder. I tried in the home folder:

**patch -p1 subdirectory/ < 201803.patch**

but that doesnt work. How can I patch from one directory above?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about Bash/Shell. Try the following. This will `cd` in *every* subdirectory of your current location and will then run the given command.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && patch -p1 < ../201803.patch" \;`

Or one by one:

`cd subdirectory && patch -p1 < ../201803.patch && cd ..`